# Altering the render array

Tags: layout-builder

We are planning to migrate to Layout Builder and is largely done except for Paragraph entities, namely one type for job titles. In D7 we used field_collection and then migrated to Paragraphs in D8 and are managing those entities in D9. In Display Suites there is a `ds_HOOK_pre_render_alter` which we took the fields of the job titles and concatenated them and returned a #markup string that works well until now.

That's because LB doesn't seem to make it easy to alter its render array. I invoked a `hook_entity_display_build_alter()` to learn how I might do that. The hook produces the `$context` which embeds the layout_builder object underneath the third_party container with the entity. Once I find that my job titles field is in play I see that the `$build` object which contains the  render array should be my target to remove the render array and replace it with my `#markup` string would be done.

But it appears that altering the render array at this point is ignored in favor of what LB is doing in the `$context->display` object.
I'm reading this [blog post](https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/migrating-paragraphs-to-layout-builder-in-drupal) about migrating Paragraphs into LB blocks but my customer needs to be able to edit the job title fields and it's not clear to me how they will do so after migrating it to an LB-style block.

Examining the component that handles my paragraph entity and its configuration I'm not clear how its determining how it will be rendered, and how I can alter it in favor of my `#markup`. Or how to write my own renderer so that it can only invoke for this single paragraph type.

Pointers appreciated, or how would you concatenate two fields in a Paragraph entity under LB?